# Switch between two scenes using the same renderer in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have been trying to find a way to be able to toggle between two scenes in three.js. I am aware that one can load a scene by using sceneLoader / exportScene combo.

Code taken from [josdirksen/learning-threejs - loading a scene](https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-08/04-load-save-json-scene.html)

```
var controls = new function () {
        this.exportScene = function () {
            var exporter = new THREE.SceneExporter();
            var sceneJson = JSON.stringify(exporter.parse(scene));
            localStorage.setItem('scene', sceneJson);
        };
        this.clearScene = function () {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
        };
        this.importScene = function () {
            var json = (localStorage.getItem('scene'));
            var sceneLoader = new THREE.SceneLoader();
            sceneLoader.parse(JSON.parse(json), function (e) {
                scene = e.scene;
            }, '.');
        }
    };
```

From my understanding of the above code you need to have the scene loaded first before you can extract it and save to local storage before you can put it back into the scene. I am also aware that SceneLoader is now deprecated.

For my senario I want to have an initial scene load and by clicking the 'scene2' button I then want to display scene2 only and if I click the 'scene1' button go back to seeing scene1 only (see fiddle below).

[A Basic Example setup](http://jsfiddle.net/w9914420/6xc41xyy/11/)

I'm not sure where to begin with this, so any pointers suggestions or advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to just switch to new scene, then why not have two scene object and one main scene. Try following code

```
/* Buttons to handle scene switch */
$("#scene2").click(function() {
  scene = scene2
})
$("#scene1").click(function() {
  scene = scene1
})

function init() {
  ....

  /* I dont think you need to add camera to scene for viewing perpose. By doing this, essentially you are adding camera object to scene, and you won't be able to see it because scene is rendered using this camera and camera eye is at same location
  */
  scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
  // Build scene1
  //  scene1.add(camera);


  scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
  // Build scene2    

  // Choosing default scene as scene1
  scene = scene1;
}
function render() {
  // Try some checking to update what is necessary

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xc41xyy/14/)

Comment: Many tnxs for both the explanation and example on how to achieve the desired effect between switching scenes. This works well for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can redraw the canvas by removing current scene `scene.remove(mesh);`  and add create new mesh add into scene

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/x8t801f5/4/

You can add custom controls using `dat.GUI` library.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.4/dat.gui.js"></script>
```

//

```
 var controls = new function() {
    // we need the first child, since it's a multimaterial
    this.radius = 10;
    this.detail = 0;
    this.type = 'Icosahedron';

    this.redraw = function() {
 // remove the old plane
      scene.remove(mesh);
      // create a new one
 // add it to the scene.
      scene.add(mesh);
   }
});
 var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(controls, 'radius', 0, 40).step(1).onChange(controls.redraw);
  gui.add(controls, 'detail', 0, 3).step(1).onChange(controls.redraw);
  gui.add(controls, 'type', ['Icosahedron', 'Tetrahedron', 'Octahedron', 'Custom']).onChange(controls.redraw);
```

**Demo** http://codepen.io/sumitridhal/pen/NjbGpB

Comment: Thank you for both examples, although it is not specific for my user case it demonstrates well the ability to remove objects from the active scene and place others instead. Your codepen shows this very well :)

Comment: You can add different onclick events for both function. I hope you got your answer.